# how to display multiple request example?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

just like that:
[image]

has multiple request options;  how to do that?

I have seen the section of openapi in [nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.cn/9/openapi); and google about it, But no good answer was found;
notice: I use nestjs/swagger not swagger about of java, there has something differents; and i can't config the swagger about of java;